# Performance improvement of query with Index scan never executed : postgresql

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance

Can the below query be improved with new Indexes.Few Index scans are "never executed"

```
explain analyze select ASSOC.ID,ASSOC.APPLICATIONCONTEXT,ASSOC.ASSOCIATIONTYPE,ASSOC.RELATEDOBJDESCRIPTION,ASSOC.VALIDFROMDATE,ASSOC.VALIDTODATE,ASSOC.CREATEDBY,ASSOC.CREATEDDATE,ASSOC.UPDATEDBY,ASSOC.UPDATEDDATE,ASSOC.STATE,ASSOC.SOURCETYPE,ASSOC.SOURCEID,ASSOC.TARGETTYPE,ASSOC.TARGETID,ASSOC.CUSTOMERID,ASSOC.PRODUCTID,ASSOC.ENTITYSPECIFICATION,ASSOC.DATA,ASSOC.PARTYTYPE,ENTITY.ID,ENTITY.ENTITYTYPE,ENTITY.VALIDFROMDATE,ENTITY.VALIDTODATE,ENTITY.CREATEDBY,ENTITY.CREATEDDATE,ENTITY.UPDATEDBY,ENTITY.UPDATEDDATE,ENTITY.STATE,ENTITY.STATEDATE,ENTITY.CATALOGCODE,ENTITY.CATALOGTYPE,ENTITY.EXTERNALID,ENTITY.REASONCODE,ENTITY.ORDERREF,ENTITY.CORRELATIONID,SER.ID,SER.TYPE,SER.SERVICECANDIDATE,SER.SERVICESPECIFICATION,SER.NAME,SER.ISSERVICEENABLED,SER.HASSTARTED,SER.ISMANDATORY,SER.STARTMODE,SER.ISSTATEFUL,SER.STATUSREASON,SER.VERSION,SER.SELLERORGANIZATION,SER.CUSTOMERORGANIZATION,RES.ID,RES.NAME,RES.ISCOMPOUND,RES.ISLOGICAL,RES.TYPE,RES.RESOURCENUMBER,RES.SERIALNUMBER,RES.SELLERORGANIZATION,RES.CUSTOMERORGANIZATION,CD.ID,CD.DATA
from (select *
      from CWT_SR_ASSOCIATION
      where SERVICEID =  '221010885') ASSOC
   left join CWT_SR_ENTITY ENTITY
      on ENTITY.ID = ASSOC.TARGETID
   left join CWT_SR_SERVICE SER
      on SER.ID = ASSOC.TARGETID
   left join CWT_SR_RESOURCE RES
      on RES.ID = ASSOC.TARGETID
   left join CWT_SR_CONTEXTDATA CD
      on CD.ID = ASSOC.TARGETID;
```

```
QUERY PLAN

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.38..115.47 rows=7 width=4473) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.10..87.40 rows=7 width=4272) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.83..63.34 rows=7 width=3317) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.56..39.28 rows=7 width=2325) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using ix_sr_assoc_serviceid on cwt_sr_association  (cost=0.28..11.21 rows=7 width=1563) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((serviceid)::text = '221010885'::text)
                     ->  Index Scan using pk_cwt_sr_entity on cwt_sr_entity entity  (cost=0.28..4.01 rows=1 width=762) (never executed)
                           Index Cond: ((id)::text = (cwt_sr_association.targetid)::text)
               ->  Index Scan using pk_cwt_sr_service on cwt_sr_service ser  (cost=0.28..3.44 rows=1 width=992) (never executed)
                     Index Cond: ((id)::text = (cwt_sr_association.targetid)::text)
         ->  Index Scan using pk_cwt_sr_resource on cwt_sr_resource res  (cost=0.28..3.44 rows=1 width=955) (never executed)
               Index Cond: ((id)::text = (cwt_sr_association.targetid)::text)
   ->  Index Scan using pk_cwt_sr_contextdata on cwt_sr_contextdata cd  (cost=0.28..4.01 rows=1 width=201) (never executed)
         Index Cond: ((id)::text = (cwt_sr_association.targetid)::text)
 Planning Time: 0.942 ms
 Execution Time: 0.073 ms
(16 rows)

Time: 1.661 ms
```

Comment: Why, is that too slow for you?

Comment: ---------- DATABASE OPERATIONS ----------
     TOTAL     AVERAGE     LONGEST    SHORTEST      COUNT  ELEMENT
  millisec    microsec       microsec         microsec
    10,522         701         142,801         589                 15,000

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add relevant information there. Perhaps you should post an execution plan for a slow execution of the query, otherwise we cannot analyze it.

Comment: 0.073 milliseconds seems quite fast to me. How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Thanks. I will collect it from team and post.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name
 Client wants as much fast as it can be. Since Analyze and Vacuum is latest so we are looking for any Index suggestion and to know what can be done with these Index scans says "Never Executed"

Comment: Explain Analyze :

Comment: You might want to pick a SERVICEID that exists, it’s short-circuiting the query as that ID does not exist in the database. Or is the question, “how to improving performance for identifying nonexistent records?”

Comment: Thanks dwhitemv.Will check with the developer about it as I don't have access also a biggner in Postgresql. I am wondering why those index scans are never executed and any useful Index can be formed